# How to rename files such that the file extension does not appear within the name using R

Tags: r, rename, export-to-excel, file-rename, batch-rename

My R code currently involves looping through a list of `.xlsm` files, transforming the data within each sheet through `function` and then output the files as a set of `.xlsx` files. Suppose my `Filelist` consists of only 2 files i.e. `Filelist = c("aaa.xlsm", "bbb.xlsm")`, my current code, stated below, will output the `.xlsx` files with file names "aaa.xlsm.xlsx" and "bbb.xlsm.xlsx" respectively.

```
Filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsm$") #extract list of files from folder that end with xlsm
lapply(Filelist, function(i) {
  df1 <- read_excel(i, sheet = "Trial1")
  df2 <- read_excel(i, sheet = "Trial2")
  df3 <- read_excel(i, sheet = "Trial3")
  df4 <- read_excel(i, sheet = "Trial4")
  write.xlsx(list(df1, df2, df3, df4), file = paste0('Out', i, '.xlsx'),
             sheetName = c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4"))})
```

How can I output the files as "aaa.xlsx" and "bbb.xlsx" instead? I understand that I can use the function `file.rename` after the `.xlsx` files have been output with the wrong names but I cannot seem to get the right syntax for this.

```
Filename <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsm.xlsx$")
Newname <- sub("^xlsm.xlsx$", "xlsx", Filename)
file.rename(Filename, Newname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tools::file_path_sans_ext` and add the extension to generate the name directly:

```r
paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext("aaa.xlm"), ".xlsx")
#> [1] "aaa.xlsx"
```